# What is the fastest way to check if value is exists in std::map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, dictionary, unordered-map

What is the fastest way to check if value is exists in the `std::map<int, int>`? Should I use `unordered map`? In this task I can't use any libraries instead of std.

Now, I am not know any ways to do this without checking all values.

Comment: .find() method searches by key, isn't it?

Comment: @IsCeo228 Oh right, I overlooked the question. Then you'll need to use an iterator over the map and iterate over it.

Comment: I can't think of anything else than just iterating over a whole container. If you need a faster way, you need to change your container to sth else, preferably sorted.

Comment: You can use the fast hash map on github. https://github.com/greg7mdp/sparsepp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way is to not do it. Don't look for *values* in maps, look for *keys* in maps.

If you need to search for a *value*, use another data structure (or a separate map).

The only way to search for a *value* in a map is linearly (O(N)), but due to caching overhead in iterating over the map data structure, it's going to be even slower than iterating over e.g. a vector.

Comment: Presumably, the data is supplied in a map. Converting to another structure could be counterproductive.

Comment: `need to search for a value, use another data structure (or a separate map)` As in *Keep an additional unordered map from value to number of occurrences.*

Answer (score 0):

You can find and element using the [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) method. Maps are usually implemented by [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which has a logarithmic search complexity.

If you need to search by a value, then you could create a reverse map, a map which has the values of the initial map as keys and the corresponding keys are the values. You can search for the value by key in the second map, which will yield the key. However, rebuilding the invert map takes resources both in time and storage, so you should only do it if you are going to search multiple times.

Comment: If only one search is to be performed, a reverse map is overkill.

Comment: @YvesDaoust true, this was mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the values, a `map` is not really different from a list or a vector. So exhaustive (linear) search is the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very big data sets (over 100'000 or so) access times into maps should not bother you, since it's gonna be really minuscule in either cases, because you just have `int` as a key already.
To check whether `value` exist in a map or not you should just use iterators or maybe `std::find_if`. Doesn't really matter what way you choose it's gonna be linear (O(n)) anyway.

```cpp
// both examples assume you using c++ 17 standart
// simple cycle variant
bool is_value_exists(auto const &map, int val) {
  for (auto const &[key, value] : map) {
    if (value == val) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
// find if version
#include <algorithm>
bool is_value_exists2(auto const &map, int val) {
  return std::find_if(
    map.begin(), 
    map.end(),
    [val](auto const &kv) { return kv.second == val; }
  ) != map.end();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"access times into maps should not bother you"_? What if I'm doing this a million times per second?

Comment: @PasserBy if you have small maps changing `std:map` to `std::unordered_map` and vice versa will not affect much. At some numbers putting them in a sorted vector and running binary search will do the trick at the same speed. It starts matter when you have a lot of data - unordered map start to have many collisions and slowly degrade to linear lookups. Regarding we still speaking about <int, int> pairs.

Comment: I don't understand the point you're making with your comment. No, searching on a `std::vector` with 100000 elements is going to be unbelievably faster than iterating over a `std::map` with 100000 elements. There is no `std::unordered_map` anywhere in your answer. But more to the point, your answer is saying, without exceptions, that the problem doesn't exist. Well, it might. And your answer leads people to believe otherwise.

Comment: My answer did not imply absence of problem, it claims that thinking of container types at OP's condition __likely__ (OP is new member) a premature optimization and he should not bother about access times since anyway his problem gonna be linear complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are entering key-value pair into the `std::map` instance, also add its pointer to the iterator of that element in an `std::vector<iterator_...>` variable.

```
myVec[value]=myMap.find(key); // at time of inserting a new key
```

This way, you can just use the value as a key(index) in the vector and directly access the map content using that pointer after comparing to nullptr.

Biggest downside is the extra book-keeping required when you remove keys from the map. If the removing operation is frequent enough, you may also use a map in place of it because if the expected value-range is too big (like all of 32bits), it is not memory-efficient.

---

You can also use the map-iteration-search as a backing-store of a direct-mapped cache (which works the fastest for integer keys(values here)). All cache-hits would be served at the cost of just a bitwise `&` operation with some value like 8191, 4095, etc (O(1)). All cache-misses would still require a full iteration of the map elements that is slow (O(N)).

So, if the cache-hit ratio is close to 100%, it can approach O(1), otherwise it will be O(N) that is slow.